# how to explode Nested data frame in PySpark and further store it to hive

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I am facing a certain issue in which i have my JSON structure as follows :-

```
{A:value,
B:value,
C:Array<Struct<A1:value,B1:value, C1:Array<struct<A2:value,B2:value>>>>
}
```

i would want it to be exploded in the following form:-

```
{
A:value,
B:value,
A1:value,
B1:value,
A2:value,
B2:value
}
```

I am using pyspark dataframes for this and couldn't find a way to explode properly. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with a sample dataframe, with the same schema as the one you specified:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = sc.parallelize([["a", "b", "c.a1", "c.b1", "c.c1.a2", "c.c1.a3"]]).toDF(["A", "B", "A1", "B1", "A2", "B2"])\
    .select("A", "B", psf.array(psf.struct("A1", "B1", psf.array(psf.struct("A2", "B2")).alias("C1"))).alias("C"))
df.printSchema()

    root
     |-- A: string (nullable = true)
     |-- B: string (nullable = true)
     |-- C: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |-- A1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- B1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- C1: array (nullable = false)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |    |    |-- A2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- B2: string (nullable = true)
```

You can explode the elements of a `StructType` inline using `*` when selecting the column (ie. `select("C1.*")` if `C1` were a `StrucType`) . Your case is a bit more complex since these `StructType`s are nested in an `ArrayType`. Nonetheless, in **Spark2**, you can access the nested elements of `StructType` contained in an `ArrayType`, the output will be an `ArrayType` of these elements:

```py
df.select("C.A1").show()

    +------+
    |    A1|
    +------+
    |[c.a1]|
    +------+
```

You can automatize this process by using the following functions:

to get a column's nested columns:

```py
def get_subcols(df, col):
    if col in df.columns:
        subschema = [s["type"]["elementType"]["fields"] for s in df.schema.jsonValue()["fields"] if s["name"] == col][0]
        return  [s["name"] for s in subschema]
    else:
        return None
```

to flatten a dataframe for one level:

```py
import re 
def flatten_df(df):
    non_nested_cols = [c[0] for c in df.dtypes if not re.match("array<struct|struct", c[1])]
    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in df.dtypes if re.match("array<struct|struct", c[1])]
    return df.select(non_nested_cols + [psf.col(c1 + "." + c2) for c1 in nested_cols for c2 in get_subcols(df, c1)])
```

Since your dataframe needs to be flattened twice, you will have to use `explode` at some point, since you'll get an `ArrayType` of an `ArrayType` of a `StructType`:

```py
df1 = flatten_df(df)
df1.printSchema()

    root
     |-- A: string (nullable = true)
     |-- B: string (nullable = true)
     |-- A1: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
     |-- B1: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
     |-- C1: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |    |-- A2: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- B2: string (nullable = true)
```

For **Spark1**, you have to use `explode` everytime:

```py
df.select("A", "B", psf.explode("C").alias("C"))\
    .select("A", "B", "C.*")\
    .select("A", "B", "A1", "B1", psf.explode("C1").alias("C1"))\
    .select("A", "B", "A1", "B1", "C1.*")\
    .show()

    +---+---+----+----+-------+-------+
    |  A|  B|  A1|  B1|     A2|     B2|
    +---+---+----+----+-------+-------+
    |  a|  b|c.a1|c.b1|c.c1.a2|c.c1.a3|
    +---+---+----+----+-------+-------+
```

Note that explode creates as many lines as there are in your array (here there is only one element in every array). Then you can `group` you dataframe back using `A, B` as keys for instance.

Comment: I am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_subcols
KeyError: 'elementType'
Error Like this is perfectly aligned to my situation please help. What should I do now