# Flattening of JSON with Joining fields on Time Stamp

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Flattening of JSON with Join on TimeStamp, Similar to the Question [Flattening a nested JSON to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57207056/flattening-a-nested-json-to-multiple-rows) , but expecting a Solution in Java, Scala, Spark, and PySpark

**Input JSON**:

> { "Sensor": "seda_01", "Location": { "City": "Los Angeles", "State": "CA" }, "rain_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.02" ], [ "1564073522", "0.01" ], [ "1564073523", "0.03" ] ], "sun_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.11" ], [ "1564073522", "0.10" ], [ "1564073523", "0.13" ] ], "wind_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.21" ], [ "1564073522", "0.21" ], [ "1564073523", "0.23" ] ] }

---

> { "Sensor": "seda_01", "Location": { "City": "Los Angeles", "State": "CA" }, "rain_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.02" ], [ "1564073522", "0.01" ], [ "1564073523", "0.03" ] ], "sun_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.11" ], [ "1564073522", "0.10" ], [ "1564073523", "0.13" ] ], "wind_value": [ [ "1564073521", "0.21" ], [ "1564073522", "0.21" ], [ "1564073523", "0.23" ] ] }

Output `dataframe`:

```
| Sensor| Location_City | Location_Sate| Rain_value_TS | Rain_value | Sun_value_TS | Sun_value |
------------------------------------------------------- ----------------
|  seda_01 | Los Angeles | CA | 1564073521 | 0.02 | 1564073521 | 0.11 |
|  seda_01 | Los Angeles | CA | 1564073522 | 0.01 | 1564073522 | 0.10 |
```

**Please Note:** 
`Rain_value_TS = Sun_value_TS`. We could use either one as Time Stamp,
For a Given TimeStamp, if we have only the Rain_value_TS,Rain_value, we could impute NULL for the Sun_Value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to explode Nested data frame in PySpark and further store it to hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157320/how-to-explode-nested-data-frame-in-pyspark-and-further-store-it-to-hive)

Comment: Why question contains 2 equivalent JSON body?

Comment: Yes.. Each Json has one to Many mapping in the output.